# If a mutex is already locked how can pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex); block the thread and still return a value at the same time?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, mutex

> The mutex object referenced by *mutex* shall be locked by calling *pthread_mutex_lock()*. If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread shall block until the mutex becomes available. This operation shall return with the mutex object referenced by *mutex* in the locked state with the calling thread as its owner.

My question is, if the mutex is already locked, and we call `pthread_mutex_lock()`, does this function return a value even though the thread is blocked, or does it return the value after the block?

Illustration of my question.

- Mutex is locked by 1st thread.
- 2nd thread tries to lock this mutex with `pthread_mutex_lock()`.

What happens? When does `pthread_mutex_lock()` return its value to the second thread?

Is it after the mutex is unlocked by the 1st thread? Or, does it return its value then blocks the 2nd thread?

Comment: It is not blocked if it is not locked, which will be true for the first thread that runs into the mutex. Only the next thread will block (until the first thread releases the mutex)

Comment: The function blocks until the mutex is available, then returns the mutex handle in locked state.  It does not return until unblocked.

Comment: @DanielFarrell  When the second thread tries to lock this locked mutex, pthread_mutex_lock() will return a value only when the mutex becomes unlocked right?

Comment: @PKramer When the second thread tries to lock this locked mutex, pthread_mutex_lock() will return a value only when the mutex becomes unlocked right?

Comment: @African_king `pthread_mutex_lock()` waits until the mutex is unlocked, THEN LOCKS IT, then returns a value to the caller

Comment: Yes, that's the observable effect. It is not a busy wait though! Threads "stopped" by a mutex will not consume any CPU cycles until the mutex unlocks.

Comment: @PKramer thansk alot

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks a lot it is clear to me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer to your question: [*pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)*](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html) will not return a value until the thread unblocks after it gets the lock. However, your code just sees a function call and *perceives* a direct return value.

Here is some more explanation.

About return values:

- If function *pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)* returns zero, you can rely on the fact that your thread has locked *mutex*: don't forget to unlock it!
- If the method returns a [non-zero error code](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html#ERRORS), the *mutex* is NOT locked by your thread, and you should not do a corresponding unlock.

The perspective of your code calling *pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)*:

- If *mutex* was NOT locked, *pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex)* will lock *mutex* and return zero immediately.
- If *mutex* was already locked *by another thread*, the function will block until your thread gets the lock on *mutex* and then return zero. However, the perspective of your code just sees a function call that returns a value: code in a thread doesn't notice its blocked. Unless, of course, you put timers around the function call.
- If the *mutex* was already locked *by your thread*, the function  deadlocks. By default, a mutex is not re-entrant and you must avoid to lock it in an already locked context, e.g. recursion. *I leave it out of scope how to do re-entrant locking*. In this case, the function simply never returns.
- If *mutex* cannot be locked for whatever reason, the function immediately returns with a [non-zero error code](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html#ERRORS).

Answer (score 2):

The description means the function will block until the mutex becomes unlocked (by its previous owner) then it locks the mutex and only after that returns. Now, the caller of the function is owner of the lock.

Comment: When the second thread tries to lock this locked mutex,  pthread_mutex_lock() will return a value only when the mutex becomes unlocked right?

Comment: @African_king No, that would be useless. The function will lock the mutex before returning.